# Тип класса, instance of

Tags: php

Есть функция:

```
function something($param = false) {

}
```

Я хочу задать определенный тип $param на вход функции. Если это массив (Array), то это работает:

```
function something(Array $param = array()) {

}
```

А если это Boolean, то почему-то нет:

> ...must be an instance of boolean, boolean given...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас вы присвоили аргументам значения по умолчанию.

Если не ошибаюсь, то где-то в документации сказано, что типизировать аргументы можно только массивом или классом. Простыми типами: строкой, логикой, числом и иными нельзя. Он, видимо, воспринимает название типов как названия классов и потому ругается, но я не уверен.

Для проверки надо написать код внутри функции, который бы проверял тип переменной с помощью соответствующих функций (is_array, is_string и т.д.) и генерировал бы исключение при несовпадении.

[Подтверждение](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.

Comment: Собственно тип я сейчас и проверяю, но хотелось сделать все через возможности php встроенные (а таких, как видимо, нет).

Comment: Угу, увы .-.

Comment: А вы не ищете того, чего туда не клали? Что есть int в php и давно ли оно там появилось? Тут вам не Python.

Comment: Ну, стоит отметить, что простая динамическая типизация там всё же присутствует: число, строка, логика.

Comment: @alexlz, я еще в своем уме :) Если я пишу Boolean, и ошибка говорит о том, что там Boolean, значит - там Boolean :)